# Prove that the limit exists.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

$\lim_{x\to0}$ ${e^{-1/ x^2}\over x}$

Prove that the limit exists, and show it that equals $0$ in order to show $g′(0)=0$. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Did you really mean to have the ${x \over x}$?

Comment: No, I've deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$1+t\le e^t\le \frac{1}{1-t} \tag 1$$

for $t<1$. We also note that $e^t>0$ for all $t$.

Then, using $(1)$ with $t=-1/x^2$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}\right|&\le\frac{1}{\left(1+1/x^2\right)|x|}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{|x|(x^2+1)}\\\\
&\to 0 \,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 0\end{align}$$

Comment: Good old Bernoulli.

Comment: @martycohen Bernoulli ... "A funny, funny guy as well as being a wonderfully talented human being."

Comment: "Take my inequality, please."

Comment: @martycohen Now that's funny. Any relationship to Bernoulli?

Comment: No, but I relate to his inequality.